# Can't install php library from GitHub to my server: "Uncaught Error: Class not found"

Tags: php

I am noob in it, let's start from this.

There is a php project on GitHub to download videos from YouTube: https://github.com/Athlon1600/youtube-downloader. I want to use it.

I downloaded all files and folders from `src` folder, then in my server via ftp manager, in site's root folder (where index.php is placed) I created an `YouTube` folder, and uploaded all from `src` there.

Now, in `index.php` I put code from the example from GitHub page:

```
use YouTube\YouTubeDownloader;
use YouTube\Exception\YouTubeException;

$youtube = new YouTubeDownloader();

try {
$downloadOptions = $youtube->getDownloadLinks("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqz-KE-bpKQ");

if ($downloadOptions->getAllFormats()) {
    echo $downloadOptions->getFirstCombinedFormat()->url;
} else {
    echo 'No links found';
}

} catch (YouTubeException $e) {
echo 'Something went wrong: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

But getting an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'YouTube\YouTubeDownloader' not found
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires Composer.

You can download the latest version from **https://getcomposer.org/download/**

The below instruction will assume that you are using XAMPP and your project is located in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyPhpProject.

If you are confident in what you are doing you should add the path to your PHP folder to the PATH system variable, so you only have to put "php" instead of the path to the EXE but that's optional.

Step 1: Open Command Prompt and run the below commands, these will change your directory to your project DIR and install Composer locally.

```
cd /d C:\xampp\htdocs\MyPhpProject
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
C:\xampp\php\php.exe composer-setup.php
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Step 2:
Now you have Composer, you should Initialize it.
Run the following command follow the on screen instructions.

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe composer.phar install
```

Your project should now be initialized and you should see a composer.json file in your project.

Finally you can install your plugins.

Just run the following command from the command prompt window:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe composer.phar require athlon1600/youtube-downloader "^3.0"
```

I also suggest the following as these will help with Debugging your PHP code:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe composer.phar nette/nette
C:\xampp\php\php.exe composer.phar tracy/tracy
```

Now add the following to the top of your file (After the opening '<?php' tag)

```
if(file_exists('../vendor/autoload.php')) ? require_once('../vendor/autoload.php') : require_once('./vendor/autoload.php');

// If you also installed Tracy add this:
use Tracy\Debugger;
```

This needs to be at the top of every php file, so I suggest creating a "header" file and calling it with `require_once()` to pre-load all your dependencies
Eg:

```
require_once('./inc/header.inc.php');
```

Comment: Shit, thanks for instructions, but, and I probably should mentioned it, I have not a server, but just a space on hosting, and it runs under Linux...

Comment: Is it possible to install that lib manually, or will it easier to just grab the code I need, probably getting off the oop, just rewriting it using functions?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be develop on your local PC then FTP the files onto the hosting, as this requires php-curl-file-downloader as well